# How to insert related object only if not exists via SQLAlchemy ORM Relationship?

Tags: python, session, sqlalchemy, orm, cascade

i'm a SQLAlchemy begginer ok?

Consider a have a on-to-may relatioship like

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "parent_table"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child")


class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = "child_table"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True) 
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("parent_table.id"))
```

I'm using repositories classes to control insert, finds and deletes for this Entities.

When a do a Parent insert, it insert all Child related objects automatically, but if there is a Child object with the same name it will raises a Integrity Error.

How do i set Child to insert only when it not exists?

I need to do this in a way that i call ParentRepository object do not extrapolate your responsibilities.

I try to put this behavior on the Child Repository class but, it doen't works when i try via Parent Repository because it's doents change default cascade insert behavior.